# Cleaning up post action in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post-redirect-get

I'm using PRG for cleaning up my posts in MVC

> On the POST action I store the controller modelstate in tempdata using an action filter and then redirect to the GET method which reloads the modelstate.

GET and POST action headers:

```
[ImportModelStateFromTempData]
public ActionResult Details(int id) { 
    var object = load(id);
    return View(object);
}

[HttpPost]
[ExportModelStateToTempData]
public ActionResult Details(MyViewModel model) { 
    update(model); return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = model.id }) 
}
```

if an error occurs I in the post action I add an error to the modelstate which invalidates the modelstate and then redirect to the get action.

My question is how best can I determine, in the GET "Details" action that the model was in an error state after the post? If the modelstate was invalid I want to skip the logic...

```
var object = load(id);
```

in the GET action. I've tried ModelState.IsValid but this does not work.

Comment: You can ask the Modelstate if its valid (it will check itself based on data annotations): if (!ModelState.IsValid) { //do your thing }. You can also add your own modelstate errors for "special" validations: ModelState.AddModelError(yourProperty, aMessage);..Although I'm not sure I actually understand your question..

Comment: @Team-JoKi He is using an action filter that imports TempData from a POST request so he follows the PRG pattern. POST to an action and ModelState is valid, shove model state in TempData and then redirect to the GET action, which will then import that ModelState so that the form has the proper validators highlighted, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't you just test "if modelState.IsValid ... do the redirect" else just return the model to the view you were on?  You want to test validity before running any update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    ModelStateDictionary modelState = filterContext.Controller.TempData[Key] as ModelStateDictionary;

    if( !modelState.IsValid )
    {
        filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add("IsValid", false);
    }
}
```

In your controller you can check the TempData["IsValid"] field instead of ModelState.IsValid:

```
if( TempData["IsValid"] != null ) // do whatever here, or skip code etc.
```

Notice how the action  filter code is in the OnActionExecuting method. YOu will keep the existing code in the OnActionExecuted:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{         ModelStateDictionary modelState = filterContext.Controller.TempData[Key] as ModelStateDictionary;

    if (modelState != null)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Merge(modelState);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Controller.TempData.Remove(Key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thought about storing the TempData[key] to alternatively check for Modelstate.IsValid but wanted to know if there's a different way. Thanks